How do I set a Non-Resolvable Private Address or a Static Random Address on an Android BLE Advertisement?
The Android documentation provides some information on how to start with BLE Advertising and the developer reference about BluetoothLeAdvertiser further provides more information on the topic.
Unfortunately it looks like there is no way to set a custom "Random private address", as defined in the Nordic course on Bluetooth Low Energy.
I know (from reading other questions here on StackOverflow) that Android already randomized the Bluetooth address when performing LE advertisements, but I would like to set my own address, as in the case of ESP32's esp_ble_gap_set_rand_addr.
Are there any options (in current or even beta Android versions) where such a feature is available?

No. As you can see in the API reference, there is no such functionality exposed. Not in the current API nor in any preview API.
Furthermore, in the BLE specification (v5.4), it says "A device shall not change its static address value once initialized until the device is power cycled.".

Is there a system API that I can use instead (assuming I can install this app as a system app)? What about root?
